# add 2d object on 3d Model using sceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, sknode, 3d-model

I am new to SceneKit and some issue on SceneKit, i need to add 2d objects on 3d model

Right now I already added 2d objects with skNode but that object is not moving with 3d model.

Like if I rotate or zoomIn and zoomout 3d model then that 2d objects also needs to move with the 3d object, when we add annotations on map

Here is link of 3d car model link with annotations, 
I need to achieve this type of output
[image]

And I have done this type of code, but object not moving.

```
   let rectangle = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20), cornerRadius: 10)
    rectangle.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 56)
    rectangle.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.807843148708344, green: 0.0274509806185961, blue: 0.333333343267441, alpha: 1.0)
    rectangle.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.439215689897537, green: 0.0117647061124444, blue: 0.192156866192818, alpha: 1.0)
    rectangle.lineWidth = 5
    rectangle.alpha = 0.4
    let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Hello World")
    labelNode.fontSize = 20
    labelNode.fontName = "San Fransisco"
    labelNode.position = CGPoint(x:100,y:100)
    shipHud.addChild(rectangle)
    shipHud.addChild(labelNode)





    sceneView.overlaySKScene = shipHud// = shipHud


    shipHud.shipHudFlashAlert(alert: "Oh My God!")
```

Please please help

Comment: Your links don’t work but you should post code and images ‘inside’ your question. Don’t use links.

Comment: Okay I am editing question..

Comment: Create a node using `SCNBillboardConstraint` instead of an overlay. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbillboardconstraint

Answer (score 0):

we can add node by SCNNode. its works for me.

```
let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 2, height: 2, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 10))
cubeNode.position = SCNVector3(10, -2, -0.2) // SceneKit/AR coordinates are in meters
sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
```